# Permission Denial: reading android.support.v4.content.FileProvider uri ANDROID pie

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, share, android-9.0-pie

I'm not able to share the screen image, it works well in old versions, it just isn't working on android pie I get this error could someone help me?

error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading android.support.v4.content.FileProvider uri content://myapp.com.provider/external/screenshot.png from pid=29478, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

code

```
  fun shareIt(imagePath: File? = this.imagePath) {

        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+ ".provider", imagePath!!)

        val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        sharingIntent.type = "image/*"
        val shareBody = "APP"
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "app share")
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody)
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "SHARE VIA"))
    }
```

Manifest code

```
  <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths" />
        </provider>
```

paths code:

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="external" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
    <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="." />
    <files-path name="files" path="." />
</paths>
```

does anyone know what should i do to solve this problem? any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It is just alike the error message says:

- you'd either have to set `android:exported="true"` (which will expose it) or
- you'd have to use method `grantUriPermission()` on it (which grants access).

Migrating from the deprecated [`android.support.v4.content.FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) to   [`androidx.core.content.FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) is suggested.

Comment: hi i'm add this line sharingIntent.addFlags ( FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION ); same error how to fix?

Comment: val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            sharingIntent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

Comment: same errror , please help me

Comment: grantUriPermission doesn't help for me

Comment: after android:exported="true"  error occured    RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must not be exported